# Convert a project from ARC to MRC

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I started my project in ARC, but for some reasons I want to change it to MRC, is there any way of doing it without having to remake my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing ARC to `No` in build settings.

Choose your project top left, then choose build settings, and enter automatic in search bar. Set **Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting** to `No`. That should be set as `Yes` if you chose ARC.

[image]

Comment: Because it not help, has got message after set this option to NO:  "error: 'retainCount' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode
'retainCount' has been explicitly marked unavailable here"

Answer (score 1):

Per @iNoob's answer, you can switch the compiler flag in your build settings.

If what you're asking is "is there an equivalent to **Edit -> Refactor -> Switch to Objective-C ARC**", I'm afraid the answer is no. You'll have to manually add in all the necessary `retain`/`release`/`autorelease` calls.

What's the reason you want to switch away from ARC (I assume building for < iOS 4.0)?